# Second and third language "search"

Tags: terminology, language-acquisition, second-lang-acquisition

In my third or fourth language, when I don't know a word or phrase, I substitute a word from my other non-native language rather than the one I obviously know in my native language.  Or if I'm looking for a Russian word, I'll say "in French, we say..." Rather than "in English, we say..."

Is there a term for this linguistic impulse?

I feel like this is an idea that should have a term.

Comment: *linguistic interference*

Comment: @Emily so you want it to specifically be a word from a language which you learned after your native one?